# Writing a list to the end of a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code:

```
included_cols = [1, 3, 5]

w = csv.writer(open(args.output,'w'))
with open('input.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    fid = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in fid:
        item = [row[i] for i in included_cols)]

        w.writerows(item)
```

for each iteration, `row` is something like `[1, 2]`...`[3, 4]` etc. But it's not writing each list as a row to `w`... Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Where is `item` even defined?

Comment: Sorry, i just update my question.

Comment: Why are you using `writerows` and not `writerow` ? Otherwise you'll be writing the columns as rows...

Comment: Are you basically trying to cut out certain columns in a csv file?

Comment: Yes I am, and that was my problem!! I was using writerows() instead of writerow. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to only select certain columns from a csv file, then you can use the following:

```
import csv
from itertools import imap
from operator import itemgetter

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    csvout.writerows(imap(itemgetter(1, 3, 5), csvin))
```

Your main problem is that you're using `.writerows` which takes an iterable, and treats each of those as a row, so giving it `[1, 2, 3]` it will write out 3 rows... While using `.writerow` will expect a single iterable, and write one row, with those as columns...

Comment: I was struggling how to inject a `included_cols` List into operator.itemgetter. Asterisk does the job: `itemgetter(*included_cols)`